# Eclipse Indigo didn't find log4j.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: eclipse, classpath, hibernate.cfg.xml

I'm using Eclipse indigo (3.7)

I added a hibernate config file and a logger config file, under "src" folder.

The application run but when I try to open the server connection I get:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader     org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder@1787005.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using     org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@183e895 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder@1787005.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@183e895 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Could not find resource: [null].
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Hibernate Exception: hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

I have no problems in other prject with the same structure.
The applications are RCP ( Rich Client Platform ).
What I need to know is how to make sure that Eclipse added correctly the "bin" and "source" folder to the classpath !! 
If I look the project with the directory perspective I see the files below "bin" folder !!

I think that because of the first problem , hibernate could'nt  find theri config file !

Any idea ?
Best Reagards

Comment: The problem was regarding to class loaders and plugin dependencies. The file hibernate.cfg.xml was in the root of core application (RCP) and the hibernate library was in a external plugin project. That external dependency was added using Dependency tab and using ADD Libray->Plugin Dependencies. The problem was in MANIFEST.MF, you need to add this line : Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: ar.com.xxx.your.library, so the classes in the external plugin uses the same class loader, than the core application.